.NET MAUI QueryProperty: Data not passed to another page
I'm developing a drawing application using .NET MAUI and Firestore. On the HomePage, I display a list of existing drawings. When I select one, I want to navigate to the DrawPage and open the selected drawing for modification.
However, the DrawingID doesn't seem to pass correctly to the DrawPage. On the HomePage, I can see that the DrawingID is correctly identified, but when navigating, it doesn't reach the DrawPage.
Additionally, the DrawPage is also used for starting new drawings, so it initializes without requiring an ID when creating a new drawing.
Any ideas why the DrawingID isn't being passed, and how I can fix this? Thanks in advance! ( sorry some of the comment are in my language)
HomePgae.Xam.cs
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
        public HomePage(HomeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        // Betöltjük a rajzokat, amikor az oldal megjelenik
        this.Appearing += async (s, e) => await viewModel.LoadUserDrawingsAsync();
    }

    private async void OnDrawingSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() is DrawingData selectedDrawing)
        {
            //Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"DrawPage?drawingId={selectedDrawing.Id}");
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///DrawPage", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "DrawingId", selectedDrawing.Id } });
            ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }   
}

DrawingPage.Xaml.cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(DrawingId), "DrawingId")]
public partial class DrawPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly DrawableCanvas _drawableCanvas;
    private readonly DrawViewModel _viewModel;
    public string DrawingId { get; set; }
    public DrawPage(DrawViewModel viewModel, FirestoreService firestoreService, FirebaseAuthClient firebaseClient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _drawableCanvas = new DrawableCanvas();
        _viewModel = new DrawViewModel(_drawableCanvas, firestoreService, firebaseClient);
        BindingContext = _viewModel;

        DrawingCanvas.Drawable = _drawableCanvas;
      
        DrawingCanvas.StartInteraction += OnInteractionStart;
        DrawingCanvas.DragInteraction += OnInteractionDrag;
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DrawingId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DrawingId: {DrawingId}"); // Debug
            await _viewModel.LoadDrawingAsync(DrawingId);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DrawingId is null or empty!");
        }
    }
    
    private void OnInteractionStart(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Touches.Any())
        {
            _drawableCanvas.StartNewLine(_viewModel.CurrentColor, _viewModel.LineThickness, _viewModel.Opacity);
            var touch = e.Touches.First();
            _drawableCanvas.AddPoint(new PointF((float)touch.X, (float)touch.Y));
            DrawingCanvas.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void OnInteractionDrag(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Touches.Any())
        {
            var touch = e.Touches.First();
            _drawableCanvas.AddPoint(new PointF((float)touch.X, (float)touch.Y));
            DrawingCanvas.Invalidate();
        }
    }

DrawingViewModel.cs the Load method:
 public async Task LoadDrawingAsync(string drawingId)
 {
     try
     {
         var userId = _authClient.User.Uid;
         var lines = await _firestoreService.LoadDrawingAsync(userId, drawingId);

         if (lines != null)
         {
             _drawableCanvas.Clear(); // Meglévő rajz törlése
             foreach (var line in lines)
             {
                 var points = line.Points.Select(p => new PointF(p["X"], p["Y"])).ToList();
                 _drawableCanvas.AddLine(points, Color.FromHex(line.Color), line.Thickness, line.Opacity);
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hiba", $"Rajz betöltése nem sikerült: {ex.Message}", "OK");
     }
 }


FireStoreSrvice.cs Load method
       public async Task<List<LineData>> LoadDrawingAsync(string userId, string drawingId)
       {
           var drawingDoc = _firestoreDb.Collection("users")
                                       .Document(userId)
                                       .Collection("drawings")
                                       .Document(drawingId);

           var snapshot = await drawingDoc.GetSnapshotAsync();

           if (!snapshot.Exists) return null;

           var lines = snapshot.GetValue<List<LineData>>("Lines");
           return lines;
       }


How is DrawPage defined in Shell?

as a shellContent, bacse I use ths in other things to :  

The issue is DrawingPage's life cycle. You're trying to use the DrawingId inside the OnAppearing() of your page. But, at this point the property DrawingId is not still set. So it will be null.
You can call the method in viewmodel once the value of the property is set, re-define your DrawingId property like below
private string _drwaingId;
public string DrawingId
{
  get
  {
    return _drwaingId;
  }
  set
  {
     _drwaingId = value;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
     {
        await _viewModel.LoadDrawingAsync(value);
     }
  }
}

